# better way to make java do random stuff?

Tags: java, if-statement, random, switch-statement

Here is the thing. recently I've been working on a project which is kind of a AI like thing. what i want to do is, i will be given a random number between 0-300 and i have to do a random thing based on that number.

now i can use

```
switch(/*number b/w 0-300*/){
case 0:
case 1:
so on to 300
```

i have tried IF-Else cases and apparently they are even more inefficient then switch cases.

but i think there must be a better way to do this because it will take like forever to make soo many cases.

EDIT: i want to mention that all of these cases are VOID so i dont know how to implement them with a list. And i am at java 7 cant change to java 8 so interface is kinda hard to manage

Comment: Are there 300 random events? Or only a selected number of random events?

Comment: What's the average thing that happens in a `case`?

Comment: I don't understand. Is your concern here about programmer time (the amount of effort it takes you to write, test, and maintain your 300 cases), or about execution time (the amount of time it takes the machine to execute the code)? In the latter case -- don't worry about that. 300 cases is nothing. In the former case -- we need more information. The hard part is going to be in writing the code *inside* each case. Is there something that makes you think you can automate that?

Comment: Could all the random things it would do be wrapped in similar methods (i.e. same number and type of args and return values)?

Comment: @ruakh my main concern is first i will try 300 cases (case 1: case2: case3:) which alone can take a lot of time and i think i kinda makes the code look in-efficient ?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils no i have to make different methods with different args and functions in every test case

Comment: @b85411 all these 300 cases contains a random event

Comment: @thvardhan What looks inefficient to a human is often not directly related to what is efficient for a computer.  To know if you are wasting time, you need to benchmark a solution, and then compare it to benchmarks for other solutions.  Since Java already does a lot of run time optimizations, it is not easy to benchmark Java, but few people can reliably look at a block of code and know if it is faster or slower than another unless it's using a different big-O pattern.  I recommend writing your code for efficient maintenance (ease of expected changes).  Switch and if / else isn't it.  Use a List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list of the things to select from

```
List<Choice> choices = new List<Choice>();
choices.add(something);
choices.add(somethingElse);
...
Choice random = choices.get(new Random().nextInt(choices.size()));
```

Comment: can you tell me how can i actually add this? i mean all of my methods are Void and it seems i have to make a object everytime i add a method to this list.

Comment: and i cant add void methods to list nor i can make a void list. (a bit of detailed code please )

Comment: nevermind i fixed it.. i completely forgot to call list.get() functions xD

Comment: @thvardhan I'm really glad you found your way to a solution.  Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface for all the "random things":

```
interface AIAction {
    public void execute();
}
```

and then collect all those actions' implementation in an array. I chose to implement each `AIAction` using a lambda, but that's ultimately up to you:

```
static AIAction[] actions = new AIAction[] {
    () -> {System.out.println("a");},
    () -> {System.out.println("b");},
    () -> {System.out.println("c");}
};
```

after that, you can just execute a random action like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int index = rand.nextInt(actions.length);
actions[index].execute();
```